# /POST a gzipped body to an ASP.NET Web API application host

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, gzip, iis-8

### Problem:

Web API 2.2 Controller won't deserialize a POST body that is gzipped; deserializes without issue if the body is not Encoded.

### Question

Why will my DelegatingHandler not pick up when a POST body is gzipped

### Anecdote:

Let's say I have 2 services (A and B) that represent a sequence.

`+GET/A returns A'
+POST/B requires A' and returns B'`

> A.cs

```
public class AController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("A")]
   public HttpResponseMessage GetA()
   {
     APrime _aprime = new APrime("A'");
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new[]{_aprime});
   }
}
```

> B.cs

```
public class BController : ApiController
{
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("B")]
   public HttpResponseMessage PostAReturnB([FromBody]IEnumerable<APrime> aprime)
   {
     if(aprime == null)return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "aprime required");
     BPrime _bprime = new BPrime("B'");
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new[]{_bprime});
   }
}
```

### No Delegating Handler

### *Unencoded Communication*

```
/GET+http://localhost:8880/A
Accept: application/json

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 20257
[{...A'...}]


/POST+http://localhost:8880/B
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 20257
[{...A'...}]

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 59466
[{...B'...}]
```

### *Encoded Communication*

```
/GET+http://localhost:8880/A
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 4000
<binary data representing a gzip encoded "A'">

/POST+http://localhost:8880/B
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 4000
Content-Encoding: gzip
<binary data representing a gzip encoded "A'">

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 15
aprime required
```

### *With a Delegating Handler*

```
public class MyRequestHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
   protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
      {
         //Do Stuff that checks if the body is compressed.
         //Decompress it
      }
      return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
   }
}
```

### *Unencoded Communication*

Handler is invoked, service fires normally

### *Encoded Communication*

Handler never fires. Fiddler displays a 504

I thought I had an A-Ha when it finally dawned on me that I was passing my Response bodies through my clipboard, so I tried to implement a custom rule in Fiddler to perform the gzip compression on the clear body content.

```
if(oSession.requestBodyBytes != null && (oSession.oRequest.headers.Exists("Client.Request-Encoding")))
{
    oSession["ui-italics"] = "true";
    if(oSession.oRequest["Client.Request-Encoding"] == "gzip")
    {

       oSession.requestBodyBytes = Utilities.GzipCompress(oSession.requestBodyBytes);
       oSession["Content-Length"] = oSession.requestBodyBytes.Length.ToString();

       oSession.oRequest["Client.CustomRule"] = "[Fiddler][Custom Rule.GZip]";

       oSession["ui-color"] = "green";
       oSession["ui-italics"] = "false";
       oSession["ui-bold"] = "true";
    }else{
       oSession["ui-color"] = "crimson";
       oSession["ui-italics"] = "true";
       oSession.oRequest["Client.Request-Encoding.Error"] = "Rule not processed. gzip is the only supported Request-Encoding value";
    }
}
```

My requests that process through this rule just go off into the nether.

Comment: You might want to give [this](https://github.com/azzlack/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression) a try. It should uncompress the request body using a `DelegatingHandler`.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma thanks for the suggestion, but Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.MessageHandlers.Compression self-identifies as obsolete in NuGet `NOTE!!! This is an obsolete package, it only installs the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server and System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Client packages`

Comment: I believe that the correct package is [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server/) which has a dependency on WebApi.Core 5.2+ (which is truly Web Api 2.2).

Comment: @FedericoDipuma that package (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server) is not appropriately decompressing requests. It had been tried, coupled with a config change to register application/json as a dynamic mime type in the httpCompression block inside the iis server config. I didn't mention this because response Encoding worked without my explicitly including any gzip related dependencies. My concern surrounds why responses are gzipped appropriately but requests are not.